# google search results page hijacked by search.interactivesplash.com

Tags: google-chrome, dns, chromium, malware, redirect

I noticed after unsubscribing from a junk mail, not sure this was a good idea, when I did a Google search using Chromium Web browser, the results page showed up, but very quickly before I could click on a url, the page I was on was redirected to 
https://search.interactivesplash.com/no-results.php

with a yellow square and a black circle inside it and a black triangle pointing to the right inside the circle on the tab.  I believe a piece of code was imported to make this happen.  I am wondering if anyone knows how to eliminate this code to prevent this from happening anymore?  Thank you

Comment: Disable all add-ons in Chromium and try again. Does the issue persist?

Comment: I didn't do anything but restart my computer and the problem went away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resetting Chrome also worked for me (so far!)

You can reset Chrome by clicking the three control dots on he upper right side of the browser window. Click on settings, then click on advanced. Scroll all the way down to the bottom. There, you will see the option to reset the browser. This will reset your startup page, new tab page, search engine, and pinned tabs. It will also disable all extensions and clear temporary data like cookies. Your bookmarks, history and saved passwords will not be cleared.

Answer (score 0):

Resetting configurations did the trick for me in Chrome.

Comment: You can improve this answer with a quick explanation of how to do the reset

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and tested my browser extensions one-by-one and found the culprit:

```
Flash Playlist 1.1.8
Flash player allows you to run your favorite flash files on any website
```

It looks like this extension is malware and has been removed from the Chrome Web Store. Delete it from your extensions list ASAP.